# MySQL Query Unique Results From Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Struggling to find the right answer for this so hopefully someone can help. It maybe so simple that I've overlooked something obvious and making it more difficult than I should be. 
I have two tables - titles [including titleIDs and titleNames], and groups [including groupIDs with title IDs they are associated with].  A titleID can have many groupIDs attached.

I'm trying to write a query that brings me back results of TitleIDs that match a criteria of groupIDs that have been selected.

So I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM titles INNER JOIN groups ON titles.titleID = groups.titleID WHERE
groups.groupID = 6 AND
groups.groupID = 24 AND
groups.groupID = 53
```

So I want to return results of only titles that are only associated with ALL these group IDS. 
The numbers will actually be replaced by what someone selects from a few tickboxes, but have hardcoded them in for purposes of this example.

I tried experimenting with a subquery but I couldn't get it to work, also I believe Subs can slow things down and I'm already going to be dealing with a lot of data.

The plan is for someone to select one or more groupIDs from a list and then return only results of Titles that are associated with all the GroupsIDs selected.

Any pointers, clues, advice on this would be really welcome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using `in()` for the group ids and matching the count of distinct groups foreach title,if 3 group ids provided so count for each title groups must be 3 so the title that has exactly these 3 groups will be returned

```
SELECT * FROM titles t
INNER JOIN groups g ON t.titleID = g.titleID 
WHERE g.groupID IN(6,24,53)
GROUP BY t.titleID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT g.groupID) = 3
```

Comment: Good answer. You should select t.\* instead of \*, however, in order not to get random g values with it. Moreover, your remark that it is possible to change the having clause to >= 3 makes no sense, because there can be no more then 3 distinct group ids when your where clause is g.groupID IN (6,24,53).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner good point yes `>=` will be of no use thanks

Comment: Thank you for that, that's great. So the IN () bit could include an array maybe so it can take however many groups are selected by the use, is that right? With the number of groups selected being stored as a variable for the COUNT (DISTINCT g....)= bit? Many thanks to both of you.